# Print values from a nested JSON

Tags: php, json

When I try to print value of a nested loop i am getting the following error Severity: Notice
Message: Trying to access array offset on value of type null.
Below is my json.

```
 $json_string='{​
    "items": [
                {​
                    "quantity": "1",
                    "combinations": [
                        {​
                            "quantity": 1,
                            "lineTotal": "0.0",
                            "price": 0.0,
                            "combinationName": "ABC"
                        }​,
                        {​
                            "quantity": 1,
                            "lineTotal": "16.0",
                            "price": 16.0,
                            "combinationName": ""
                        }​,
                        {​
                            "quantity": 1,
                            "lineTotal": "0.0",
                            "price": 0.0,
                            "combinationName": " DEF"
                        }​
                    ],
                    "price": "0.0",
                    "menuItemName": "Classic Hummus",
                    "menuItemId": "37300"
                }​,
                {​
                    "quantity": "1",
                    "combinations": [
                        {​
                            "quantity": 1,
                            "lineTotal": "0.0",
                            "price": 0.0,
                            "combinationName": " HIJ"
                        }​,
                        {​
                            "quantity": 1,
                            "lineTotal": "0.0",
                            "price": 0.0,
                            "combinationName": " KLM"
                        }​,
                        {​
                            "quantity": 1,
                            "lineTotal": "0.0",
                            "price": 0.0,
                            "combinationName": ""
                        }​
                    ],
                    "price": "16.0",
                    "menuItemName": "Classic Hummus",
                    "menuItemId": "37300"
                }​,
                {​
                    "quantity": "1",
                    "combinations": [
                        {​
                            "quantity": 1,
                            "lineTotal": "0.0",
                            "price": 0.0,
                            "combinationName": "Egg, Avo & Hummus"
                        }​,
                        {​
                            "quantity": 1,
                            "lineTotal": "0.0",
                            "price": 0.0,
                            "combinationName": "Chicken Tikka & Curry Hummus Wrap"
                        }​,
                        {​
                            "quantity": 1,
                            "lineTotal": "0.0",
                            "price": 0.0,
                            "combinationName": ""
                        }​,
                        {​
                            "quantity": 1,
                            "lineTotal": "0.0",
                            "price": 0.0,
                            "combinationName": "Chicken Musakhan & Hummus"
                        }​,
                        {​
                            "quantity": 1,
                            "lineTotal": "0.0",
                            "price": 0.0,
                            "combinationName": ""
                        }​,
                        {​
                            "quantity": 1,
                            "lineTotal": "0.0",
                            "price": 0.0,
                            "combinationName": "Chicken Shawarma & Hummus Wrap"
                        }​,
                        {​
                            "quantity": 1,
                            "lineTotal": "0.0",
                            "price": 0.0,
                            "combinationName": ""
                        }​,
                        {​
                            "quantity": 1,
                            "lineTotal": "0.0",
                            "price": 0.0,
                            "combinationName": "Supergreen Falafel & Hummus Wrap"
                        }​,
                        {​
                            "quantity": 1,
                            "lineTotal": "0.0",
                            "price": 0.0,
                            "combinationName": ""
                        }​
                    ],
                    "price": "93.0",
                    "menuItemName": "Wraps Bundle For 5",
                    "menuItemId": "37328"
                }​
            ]
 }';
```

Below is my code. When I try to print value of a nested loop i am getting Severity: Notice Message: Trying to access array offset on value of type null. Below is my code.

```
$obj = json_decode($json_string,true);
$order_contents = $obj['items'];

  foreach($order_contents as $order) {
    $menuItemName = $order['menuItemName'];
    $price = $order['price'];
    $combinations = $order['combinations'];

    foreach($combinations as $combination) {
      echo $menuItemName.'-'.$combination['combinationName'].'-'.$price.'.';
    }
   }
```

Comment: You have a zero-width space character (Unicode code point 8203) after every `{` character. That's not valid in JSON.

Comment: Where did the JSON come from? No normal JSON encoder would add those characters, it must have gone through a word processor of some kind that added unneeded formatting.

Comment: Thank you @Barmar it was zero-width space character issue. Copied the JSON from Microsoft Teams